# Where can I find older versions of the iPhone sample code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sample

I'm trying to find some of the old iphone sample code, becuase it seems like apple will only let you download the most recent versions (compatable with iphone 3.2 +). Is there an archive of these someplace, is there a reason that they remove the older versions of there samepl code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a lot of them would use depreciated classes which could confuse new developers. The ones I have seen disappear (only a couple) have been replaced by an updated version.

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, I've been trying to develop for iPhone os 3.1, the only examples I can find are sdk 4.0 (the iphone simulator 3.2 is the iPad.

Comment: @testerthetester - Apple tries to push developers to adopt the new OSs as soon as they are released.  Most of the samples still work with 3.0 as a deployment target.  Several of the older examples also had bugs within them (memory leaks, etc.) so they may not want those to be available to developers since many people tend to just copy and paste code from them.